# Weighted Traversal Algorithm (Breadth first is better?)

Tags: python, algorithm, performance

I'm having trouble designing an algorithm for a traversal problem.

I have a Ship that I control on a 2D grid and it starts on the very bottom of the grid. Each tile of the grid has a value (between 0 and 1000) equal to how much 'resource' is in that tile.

The Ship can `go_left()`, `go_up()`, `go_right()` or `stay_still()`

If the ship `stay_still()` it collects 25% of it's current tile's resource (rounded up to the nearest int).

If the ship uses a move command, it needs to spend 10% of it's current tile resource value rounded down. Moves that cost more than the ship has collected are illegal. (So if a ship is on a 100, it costs 10 to move off the 100, if it's on a 9 or less, moving is free).

The goal is to find a relatively short path that legally collects 1000 resource. Returning a list of the move order to corresponds to the path.

I naturally tried a recursive approach:

In sudo-code the algorithm is:

```
alg(position, collected, best_path):
  if ship has 1000:
    return best_path
  alg(stay still)
  if ship has enough to move:
    alg(try left)
    alg(try up)
    alg(try right)
```

If you want a closer look at the actual syntax in python3 here it is:

```
    def get_path_to_1000(self, current_position, collected_resource, path, game_map):
        if collected_resource >= 1000:
            return path

        path_stay = path.copy().append(stay_still())
        self.get_path_to_1000(current_position, collected_resource + 
                 math.ceil(0.25 * game_map[current_position].value),
                 path_stay, game_map.copy().collect(current_position))

        cost = math.floor(0.1 * game_map[current_position].value)
        if collected_resource >= cost:
            direction_list = [Direction.West, Direction.North, Direction.East]
            move_list = [go_left(), go_up(), go_right()]
            for i in range(3):
                 new_path = path.copy().append(move_list[i])
                 self.get_path_to_1000(
                      current_position.offset(direction_list[i]), 
                      collected_resource - cost, new_path, game_map)
```

The problem with my approach is that the algorithm never completes because it keeps trying longer and longer lists of the ship staying still.

How can I alter my algorithm so it actually tries more than one option, returning a relatively short (or shortest) path to 1000?

Comment: No, this is a variant of Dijkstra's algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm Dijkstra uses "shared memory", so it does not scale exponentially, but linear in the number of edges.

Comment: You won't solve this with recursion. Look into heuristics like Simulated Annealing

Answer (score 0):

The nature of this problem (ignoring the exact mechanics of the rounding down/variable cost of moving) is to find the shortest number of nodes in order to acquire 1,000 resources. Another way to look at this goal is that the ship is trying to find the most efficient move with each turn.

This issue can be solved with a slightly modified version of Dijksta's algorithm. Instead of greedily choosing the move with the least weight, we will choose the move with the most weight (greatest number of resources), and add this value to a running counter that will make sure that we reach 1000 resources total. By greedily adding the most efficient edge weights (while below 1000), we'll find the least number of moves to get a total 1000 resources.

Simply keep a list of the moves made with the algorithm and return that list when the resource counter reaches 1000.

Here's a helpful resource on how to best implement Dijkstra's algorithm:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm-greedy-algo-7/

With the few modifications, it should be your best bet!